# Discord bot not responding when being called

Tags: python, discord, bots, replit

your text Okay, so I am having this problem while creating a discord bot for the Truth and Dare game...
The bot goes online, and it has permission to be an admin, to read and send messages but it still doesn't respond to my commands,
I am using Replit for running the bot I see no error messages while running it, it is just the command thingie, how do I trigger it?  I would be grateful if someone help me with the code, please

Code :

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.typing = False
intents.presences = False

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

truth_questions = [
"Have you ever lied to your best friend?",
"What is your biggest fear?",
"Have you ever cheated on a test?",
"What is your most embarrassing moment?",
"Have you ever stolen anything?",
"What is your secret talent?",
"Have you ever been caught telling a lie?",
"What is your biggest regret?",
"Have you ever eavesdropped on someone's conversation?",
"What is the most trouble you have ever been in?"
]

dare_tasks = [
"Do 10 push-ups right now!",
"Sing a song out loud!",
"Tell a joke to everyone!",
"Do a funny dance!",
"Speak in a foreign accent for the next 5 minutes!",
"Call a random friend and say 'I love you!'",
"Do a handstand against a wall!",
"Send a message to your crush saying you like them!",
"Eat a spoonful of a spicy sauce!",
"Do a cartwheel in a public place!"
]

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {bot.user.name}")

@bot.command()
async def truth(ctx):
    question = random.choice(truth_questions)
    await ctx.send(f"Truth: {question}")
    await bot.process_commands(ctx.message)

@bot.command()
async def dare(ctx):
    task = random.choice(dare_tasks)
    await ctx.send(f"Dare: {task}")
    await bot.process_commands(ctx.message)


bot.run('Token')
```

I tried looking for codes created by other people, its all old from 2022 and I see the codes have been running well from that time, but mine still doesn't work,  I tried searching for multiple solutions from people who have the same problem but still didn't work, I even asked AI to check why the code is not responding and even with the solutions provided, it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `message_content` intent. `discord.Intents.default()` includes all intents except for `presences`, `members`, and `message_content`. Your edited block should look like this:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```